# Undefined reference to in c

Tags: c, makefile

Though this sounds to be a noobs question, I am facing a weird situation.
The project that I am trying to build has a well organised files. Each application module is kept in a seperate folder with its source (*.C) and include files in the subfolder. Every folder has a make file and there is a master make file in the drive.
I have added a C source file in one of the module. If I call a function from a c file kept in different folder, it gives an error "undefined reference to", though there are many functions called from different C files kept in different modules' C files.

I guess the make files need to be modified. But I am a begineer using make. I am unable to figure out what to modify and where.

Comment: sorry, with the current amount of information , we can't help you. it's unclear.

Comment: Notice that `*.C` files (with a capital C) are generally C++ files,  not C files. But I suggest using `.cc` or `.cpp` for C++ source files, and `.c` for C source files

Comment: what more info should i give, @SouravGhosh. All files are c language source files. The files are being (cross) compiled for another linux environment (ARM9)

Comment: nope, that's not required. The directory structure, the makfile, your addition, the error message......Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Have you wrote headers to export your c file routine? Are headers files included in c file that use function from another c file?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out mate @SouravGhosh. I dont know how to write english, will you teach me?? #Sarcasm

Comment: @D.7 that is a question I should be asking you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Makefile will compile your files based on some rules (identified by `:`).

If your Makefile is written in a way to *not* compile every `.c` file (which I recommend), you might have to write the rule for the new file yourself.

The rules are built like this:

```
rulename: dependencies
    command1
    command2
    command3...
    ...
```

`rulename` is the name of the rule. This is usually the name of the `.o` file you want to get from your .c file.
`dependencies` are files upon which this rule "depends" (meaning if any file changes, the rule is out of date and must be "made" again).
`command[n]` are the shell-commands to use when **making** this rule. These commands are run **each one in a different shell** (This means you can't do `cd ....` and then `gcc -c ....` in another line, you have to do them both in the same line : `cd .... && gcc -c ....`).

A concrete example should be:

```
my_file.o: my_file.c my_file.h main_header.h other_things.h
    gcc -o my_file.o -c my_file.c
```

Place this in the Makefile on the *same level* as your .c file.
If your source files are in a subfolder and there is no Makefile at this level, put in in the closest one and add paths when calling gcc.

There are [rule-writing shortcuts and variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) you can use when writing your rules.

Comment: The problem here is that master make file that i have calls make files in each subfolder. and every make file then performs compilation. i have included header files properly in C source file. 
The referrencing is still a problem. Also no-where in make there is any listing of paths.

the master make has
`TQCALLFBBS =   Utils \

   Xml \

   XmlParse \`

Comment: @D.7 The make files in each subfolders should contain either a generic `.c.o:` rule or other rules to compile the source files. If the rule is `.c.o:` you shouldn't need modify, if not put your new rule there. I can't help you more than that with the info you provided.